# How to programatically register an Azure AD application without tenant ID?

Tags: c#, automation, azure-active-directory, adal, azure-ad-graph-api

I read these threads but am not really satisfied with the answers:

- [How to add application to Azure AD programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31684821/)
- [How to add application to Azure AD programmatically without having any initial clientId registered?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41554293/)
- [Adding Applications programmatically in Azure AD using Client Credentials Flow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34762918/)

I think I have a scenario that currently is not supported.

We are building an application that consolidates info about a customer's on-premise infrastructure *and* cloud environment in a database. It should also gather info about e.g. Office 365 users and subscriptions. Here's the customer scenario:

1. Download and install the app *on-premise*.
2. Configure data sources (similarly to the *Inventory and Assessment Wizard* in [MapToolkit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb977556.aspx)). Also point the app to Office 365 subscription(s) at this point.
3. Run the app to gather asset info into your database.

They need to register the app in Azure AD and provide it access to Microsoft Graph for step 2 to work. If they're techie enough to find their tenant id, register the app through the Azure portal or with PowerShell, and copy ID's into the app's configuration file, that is not a problem. But I cannot streamline the configuration process for the less tech-savvy user.

Basically I want to do something in compiled C# that today is already possible with PowerShell: login as a directory administrator and register an application. So I don't see a security concern here.

We have a similar scenario running that does work, where we set up the app as a multitenant application in our Azure AD, and customers provide consent to access their Office 365 subscription on a web page. But that's not the idea. It's their data, there's no reason to run it through our tenant.

Maybe I'm missing the point completely and there is an easy way to implement this. But I've been sifting for weeks through AzureAD doc and samples now and I don't see it. Any help or info to support this scenario is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here as an answer:

You can register a multi-tenant app in your tenant.

That app can be granted access to create a new app in the customer's tenant. Then you have a new single-tenant in your customer's AAD.

That app should be granted access to the resources your solution needs access to. That is what we ended up with for our solution.

The customer can revoke access to the multi-tenant app that has write access to AAD as soon as the new app in their own tenant has been created.

Answer (score 0):

All objects in Azure Active Directory live within a Tenant, including Application Objects. When referencing any object in the directory, you must first establish tenant context, and then you are allowed to query the data within that tenant. There is nothing we provide (that I know of) that exists above the top level Tenant structure.

When you say "It's their data, there's no reason to run it through our tenant." I feel like there is a slight misunderstanding of how data flows from the directory to your application.

All OAuth 2 client applications need to be registered somewhere. All different service providers offer some sort of client registration process. Azure Active Directory simply takes advantage of the existing Tenant structure to register applications. This also allows for a number of other features like admin controls, user assignment to apps, conditional access policies, etc...

Now when you register a multi-tenant application in your tenant, you are really just establishing a home for where your client's registration is stored. No data actually makes it's way into your tenant, or is stored in your tenant. We simply reference the Application Object in your tenant to understand what the current configuration of the application is.

We do ask the users who use your application to provide consent for your app to get that data. When users sign up to use AAD, Microsoft makes a promise to those users to keep their personal and private data safe. (I am sure we use much more legal terms than that, but you get the idea.) We cannot simply hand over things like user's phone numbers, email addresses, etc without first knowing that the user is OK to hand that data over to you. There is nothing you can do to bypass consent, and there really shouldn't be a way to do this.

However, these concepts are slowly changing with the future of our application model. In App Model V2, we allow AAD Users or people with Personal Accounts to register applications that allow both AAD and Personal Accounts to sign in. This means that you, without an AAD account, could create and register apps for the scenario you described above.

Learn more about that here:
[Sign-in Microsoft Account & Azure AD users in a single app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-appmodel-v2-overview)

Comment: Thx @Shawn. I understand the concept of tenants and the relation between the app object and its service principal. If I register the app in my tenant, request consent, and have my customers run it on-premise, wouldn't all instances share the same clientId/secret? Wouldn't that be a huge security concern? To solve that I could register the app in my tenant ánd run it as a central service in my subscription under my control. Data would flow through our subscription than. The only other option I see is to register it in their tenant, with their unique client credentials. Thx for the link.

Comment: @flip You can register a multi-tenant app in your tenant. That app can be granted access to create a *new* app in the customer's tenant. Then you have a new single-tenant in your customer's AAD. That app should be granted access to the resources your solution needs access to. That is what we ended up with for our solution. The customer can revoke access to the multi-tenant app that has write access to AAD as soon as the new app in their own tenant has been created.

Comment: In a multi-tenant app there is only one client id and client secret indeed. But the whole point is that your app keeps those secret. When a user signs in, your app can get access tokens to call APIs as itself/with user's rights on their tenant. But especially with app-only permissions, *it is* down to your app to only request for data for the currently logged in user's tenant. Since technically it could request for data for any tenant that has gone through consent.

Comment: @flip I would agree with RasmusW's approach as it is the most scale-able, and probably how I would design a service that needs to run on-premise and have a unique secret that the customer controls. The other option, which doesn't scale as well, would be to simply use AAD PowerShell to create a service principal in the tenant with a specific App ID GUID. Then, your code will always work in customer tenants that have done the correct set up. Finally, I want to make sure you are aware of Native Client apps which do not have secrets (as opposed to confidential clients) and can be multi-tenant.

Comment: @RasmusW, I took the same approach. If it works for your solution, it should also work for mine. Not quite there yet, though. If you reply instead of comment I'd be happy to mark your reply as the answer. Thx.

Comment: Exactly, @juunas. The processed data is unique to the customer, and so should be the client credentials. There is no reason for this to be a multi-tenant app, other than the fact that the process to create a single-tenant app is more complex for the customer than to consent to a multi-tenant app. I would like to automate that process so the customer does not have to copy the generated client id and secret into the app's config, etc.

Comment: @Shawn,the inventory collection should be scheduled so it will run without a logged in user. So I don't think a native app is an option. I will take RasmusW's approach. I would like to point out, though, that it's a bit cumbersome having to create a multi-tenant setup-app that creates a single-tenant app, if all I want to do is provide code that the customer can use independent of me as provider.