# Converged applications Azure AD v2, register programmatically

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-active-directory

Hi i trying figure out how register app in https://apps.dev.microsoft.com programmatically.

[image]

Any idea?

Comment: Check this previous thread:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31684821/how-to-add-application-to-azure-ad-programmatically

Comment: @trebleCode Those don't apply for v2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way to register Azure AD v2.0 applications at this point in time is through the Microsoft Graph API beta endpoint.

You'll need to use the [`beta/resource/Application` endpoint](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/resources/application) and perform a HTTP POST with a valid access token.  This is a beta endpoint meaning it may change in the future and is not recommended for production.

[Here's](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/get-started) the MS Graph getting started to help use the API.