# Registering Application / Obtaining Tenant information from Azure programmatically (C# .NET Core)

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, azure-active-directory

Does Azure support a programmatic way of registering an application via the users Microsoft account (Using Azure Active Directory)?

[Example 1](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-openidconnect-aspnetcore/)

I am unable to find anything through the Microsoft docs. Everything related to this indicate a manual application registration has to be done, then manually entered. However, I want my application to support multiple tenants without having to manually input all the information into environment variables.

I would like my application to register itself after a user has signed into their Microsoft account and allow access to my application (similar to Github integration). With that registration, it can then pull down the users tenant information and generate a key for itself.

Edit: I have found some other answers on StackOverflow that mentions [using GraphAPI after obtaining a bearer token from Microsoft](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31684821/how-to-add-application-to-azure-ad-programmatically)

Is this still the best way of doing this?

Comment: Isn't this basically a multi-tenant app? :) You register the app in your tenant, and then the users can login with their account, and once they accept the permissions the app wants, a service principal gets created in their tenant, giving you access there as well.

Comment: You should take a look at Azure Management Fluent API https://github.com/Azure/azure-libraries-for-net.

Comment: @juunas Actually, yes, maybe my approach is wrong on this. Multi-tenant is exactly what I'm going for. I've never taken this approach but it does appear Microsoft has a consent framework. I'll try this out and report back!